# Error:(25, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: android, gradle

Возникает ошибка при сборке проекта, подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Пробовал менять настройки gradle, ставил и локальную оболочку gradle и по дефолту которая идет, ставил галочку офлайн работа, снимал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]